# How to remove lines from image Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing, getimagedata

So given an image of a data-table, I would like to remove all the lines. I classify a line as continuous pixels, whether vertical or horizontal.  [image]

So the result would be all the grid lines removed, leaving essentially text and numbers.

Is there a way to remove all lines using Javascript's image data?
Like what I have in mind is to loop through a 2D array containing the pixels of this 2D image and find all lines and change it's color to its surrounding color, making it 'disappear'. 
 So this would modify the image data of the image.

Comment: Sounds like an OpenCV task!

Comment: But OpenCV has never been ported to Javscript.  Can you provide me the link to a JS library? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to do the particular task, but this may help. https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/df/df7/tutorial_js_table_of_contents_setup.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to loop over all the pixel rows, check if all pixels are "black" and if they are, turn them white. Then do the same for all pixel columns.

```
for(var i=0; i<imageData.width; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<imageData.height; j++){
        var pixel = imageData[i * imageData.width + j];
        vas isBlack = checkIfBlack(pixel);

        if (isBlack === false) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(var j=0; j<imageData.height; j++){
        for(var k=0; k<4; k++){
            imageData[i * imageData.width + j + k] = 255;
        }
    }
}

for(var i=0; i<imageData.height; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<imageData.width; j++){
        var pixel = imageData[i + j * imageData.width];
        vas isBlack = checkIfBlack(pixel);

        if (isBlack === false) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for(var j=0; j<imageData.height; j++){
        for(var k=0; k<4; k++){
            imageData[i + j * imageData.width + k] = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

The variable `imageData` is constructed as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

I have left out the function `checkIfBlack()` intentionally. The simplest implementation would be to check if the RGB channels are all 0 (or below a threshold at least).

```
function checkIfBlack(pixel, threshold) {
    threshold = threshold || 0;

    for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if(pixel[i] > threshold) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most general features in opencv has now been ported  in Javascript(opencv.js).
Here is the link to hough transform.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/de6/tutorial_js_houghlines.html

You can identify the horizontal and vertical lines using hough transform and remove them.

Otherwise if you want to implement your own code in Javscript, you can find all the connected components as described here- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling.

Post connected component labeling you can remove the large connected components based on its geometric dimension and pixel density.

Hope that helps :)